# Increment value in Excel column depending on existing values in other column

Tags: excel

I have 4 columns in Excel: A, B, C, and D. I want two of the columns (C & D) to auto-populate based on the input in the other two columns (A & B). The first column that auto-populates (C) should start at 1 and increment each time a new value is added in the same row of column B. Column D should also start at 1 and increment each time a new value is added in the same row of column B, however, if column A has the same value as the previous row (i.e., a date) then it should not increment but instead be the same value as column D in the previous row. Additionally, if a value in column B is repeated, but with a different value (i.e., a date) in column A, then it's corresponding value in column C should be the same as before, but the value in column D should still increment because the value in column A is new.

To visualize:

```
A         B      C   D   
Jan. 5    red    1   1
Jan. 5    gre    2   1
Jan. 6    pin    3   2
Jan. 6    pur    4   2
Jan. 7    bla    5   3
Jan. 7    blu    6   3
Jan. 8    red    1   4
Jan. 8    gre    2   4
Jan. 9    yel    7   5
Jan. 9    ora    8   5
```

I hope this makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For column C, it appears that you want the count to reset when the text has been found before. Will this start a new round of counting until that section that started at 1 repeats again, or should it reset any time a value is repeated from previous counts?

Comment: @SeanC great question! If the text has been found before, the value in column C should correspond with the value the same text had in the earlier row. When a new value is entered after that, the count in column C should continue to increment with unique values. I've edited the question to better show what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "A" is in cell A1, hardcode 1 in C2 and D2 then in C3 and downwards:

```
=iferror(index($C$2:$C2,match(B3,$B$2:$B2,0)),max($C$2:$C2)+1)
```

and in D3 and downwards:

```
=if(A3="","",if(A3=A2,D2,max($D$2:D2)+1))
```

Comment: Actually, when there is an empty row, the count in column D resets. How would I fix that so that the count continues from the most recent value in the column?